# New adonis project: server starts but not listening on port

Tags: port, adonis.js

I have created new adonis project using command

> adonis new yardstick
>
> cd yardstick

I did not do any changes, I have just run command to start server. Server started, but it is not listening on port. When I start server using "node" command, it works and port is listening. Where can I look to solve a problem, so it would work with adonis command, too?

Solution that does not work:

> adonis serve --dev

Solution that works:

> node server

Comment: can you copy or create .env file if not then try cp .env.example .env then start server may be it's work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that port `3333` is free.Then in your browser type `localhost:3333`

Comment: yes, the port 3333 is free. As I mentioned in my question, the same port is listening when I use "node server" command.